# GCP Cloudsql Mysql Replica unresponsive after mass delete on Master

Tags: mysql, replication, google-cloud-sql

We have a Master/Replica configuration for Mysql innodb(5.7.32) databases in Cloud SQL... We have a single Table (let's call it Master table) partitioned on Two keys having both primary and non-clustered indexes... It's a row-based replication with automatic disk increase on both instances... It's **not** a HA configuration so it's not a failover replica...

*What we're trying to do...* We're trying to purge the master table back to N number of days... This is done for multiple reasons so let's say this is a client requirement...

*What's the issue...* Whenever we're purging the master table it just stalls the replica, it deletes a certain number of rows on the replica and then just passes out... The number of records in a single purge is around 5 million rows... [The time the purge starts on the master, the lag starts...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmfoo.png) It's a totally repeatable issue... we know it's caused because it's a row-based, sequential replication so

*What we've tried so far...*

1. Increasing the size of the replica, we've given it 104 GB RAM but
   the lag doesn't go...
2. Restarting replica
3. RESET SLAVE
4. Trying enabling parallel replication https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/manage-replicas#configuring-parallel-replication... every single time I tried this it failed with an 'Unknown error occurred'...
5. Trying setting it to a *Statement-based replication* by the `SET binlog_format="STATEMENT"` command but the "root" user doesn't have the privilege and gets an `'access denied'` error...

Now the question...
*what am I missing in my:*

1. explanation
2. mysql configuration
3. method

Thanks

Comment: any solution you found for this ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291140/gcp-cloudsql-mysql-replica-unresponsive-after-mass-delete-on-master